# HTML: Why isn't this css file being used

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use HTML and just call a CSS file which contains just a width and heaigh as well as colour for an object but it's not displaying the box.

HTML:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
    <title>Harry's Website</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div = id"navigation">
    </div>
    <div = id"header">
    </div>
    <div = id"contentleft">
    </div>
    <div = id"contentright">
    </div>
    <div = id"footer">
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#navigation
{

    width: 100%;
    height: 35px;
    background-color: #000;

}

#header
{

    width: 100%;
    height: 35px;
    background-color: #000;

}

#contentleft
{

    width: 100%;
    height: 35px;
    background-color: #000;

}

#contentright
{

    width: 100%;
    height: 35px;
    background-color: #000;

}

#footer
{

    width: 100%;
    height: 35px;
    background-color: #000;

}
```

Comment: Your HTML syntax for the element ID's is incorrect. Should be `<div id="navigation">` etc.

Comment: How do I ID them correctly?

Comment: Oh come on, this should be basic stuff, and the guy even told you how to ID them correctly. You have: ``<div = id"navigation">``, which should actually be ``<div id="navigation">``, where did you learn to HTML?

Answer (score 4):

Because your html is false try this :

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
    <title>Harry's Website</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="navigation">
    </div>
    <div id="header">
    </div>
    <div id="contentleft">
    </div>
    <div id="contentright">
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

Give an id using the HTML shown below

```
<body>
    <div id="navigation">
    </div>
    <div id="header">
    </div>
    <div id="contentleft">
    </div>
    <div id="contentright">
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
     </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, what was wrong with mine, they look exactly the same?

Comment: You did not put an equals sign in.

Comment: Notice, yours says div = blah, mine says div id= blah

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
 <div = id"navigation">
 </div>
```

to this:

```
 <div id="navigation">
 </div>
```

Notice location of equal signs.

Answer (score 1):

You may have the href path wrong,  and you are missing the starting quote for all the id's

Comment: The path is 100% correct, how would I have the starting quote then?

Comment: Happens to all of us!